# What keeps marking my files as read-only

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, file-permissions, write-protect

Is there any way for me to find out which application keeps marking my files and folders Read-Only?

I'm a developer working on W10x64 with VS2015 and souce control via TFS.
Every now and then (I havn't found a pattern...yet) my project folder and files gets marked as read-only, which causes issues with local debugging and compilation.

This is getting very frustration, and I'm just about to write a application that watches my filesystem to keeps file write enabled.

However, maybe there's a more "sane" way to find the culprit?

Comment: Where is the folder located on your computer? Do you copy/paste files or folders into the directory from another source?

Comment: Files located on e-drive - as in: non-system drive. Sometimes I copy files myself, sure. But sometimes entire folders are marked. I suspect the TFS Source Control from VS2015 marking files as readonly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had enough and wrote a small app to monitor my file attributes.

Turns out every time I sync with TFS, files are marked as read-only.
I cannot find a vanilla solution to prevent this, so I tweaked aforementioned app to reset attributes whenever changed.

Don't know if this will cause other issues. But for now my main one has been resolved.